# Rails 4 @variables and if statement without forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, ruby-on-rails-4, instance-variables

I will first clarify that the source of my problem is that I can't seem to be able to build a proper hash to be accepted by the create method with strong parameters. I am trying to do it programmatically without a form. So if I figure out how to build that hash then the problem is solved.

This should be a basic questions but I don't seem to be able to find an easy answer to that issue. I've been using rails 4 for a little while and it's working fine while I am using forms and user inputs.

However, I am trying to do something programmatically and I am bumping agains some Rails conventions.

If I am trying to use just a simple create! statement (shown below), Rails is trying to use the create method and I am bumping into a strong parameter exception.

```
def computenew
 Slot.create!(day_id: "1", grid: "9", break: "9", slot_no: "94", commercial_id: "1")
end
```

In this case, I get the following error:

> ActionController::ParameterMissing in SlotsController#create
>
> param not found: slot

and the extracted source:

```
def slot_params
  params.require(:slot).permit!
end
```

To clarify, I am calling the "computenew" method from a button on the "index.html.erb" file associated with the "slot" MVC. The button code is the following:

```
<%= button_to "Compute slot", :method=> "computenew" %>
```

So basically, I don't pass the "slot" but I though that I was creating just that in putting the parameters in.

On the other hand, if I move the code to the "create" method then it works fine but I don't have the possibility to create it from a form anymore like this:

```
def create
 @slot = Slot.new(day_id: "1", grid: "9", break: "9", slot_no: "94", commercial_id: "1")
  if @slot.save
   flash[:success] = "Slot Created"
   redirect_to Slot
 else
  render 'new'
 end
end
```

So, what I am trying to do is to create an instance variable and use it as a case the "create" method so that I can keep both functionalities.

So this should be very simple right? Create an instance variable, set it to "true" and then use it in the "if" statement to handle both cases. But this simple task seems to elude me, there is something I don't get. Maybe I am not using the right tool for this? Here's what is not working.

Calling the "computenew" method from a form button and trying to initialize the "@computemode" instance variable to true.

Then calling the "create" method

```
def computenew
 @computemode = true
 create
end
```

Then in the create method I am trying to evaluate the "@computemode" instance variable with an if statement

```
def create
 if @computemode.true?
  @slot = Slot.new(day_id: "1", grid: "9", break: "9", slot_no: "94", commercial_id: "1")
  if @slot.save
   flash[:success] = "Slot Created"
   redirect_to Slot
  else
    render 'new'
  end
 else 
  @slot = Slot.new(slot_params)
  if @slot.save
   flash[:success] = "Slot Created"
   redirect_to Slot
  else
    render 'new'
  end
 end 
end
```

I've also tried to put something in the "@computemode" instance variable and use "nil" and "==" comparators but this doesn't seem to do the trick either.

Like I said, it should be pretty basic and I have done this kind of constructs in other language but it just seem to be a little something that I don't get about Ruby or Rails.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would suggest that you revert to the scenario that is failing with the strong parameters and fix that exception. This link provides several useful examples on how to use them: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html  If that doesn't help, please update the question with the actual strong paramter error you're getting.

Comment: @fmendez I have updated with the exception. I have read your link (I had already seen it) but it still doesn't solve my problem. There is probably something very obvious that I don't get... but this is why I post the question... I don't get it! ;-)

Comment: In your initial example, are you calling `Slot.create!` inside of your view file?

Comment: @jstim I am calling from inside the slot controller.

Comment: I think the problem must be with the for, can you please add your form's code???

Comment: @hmartinezd That's the whole point of this, I am trying to save the record from within the controller without form. If I replace the create method with the code that create it from within the controller it works (but then I loose the ability to also do it with a form). If I do it through another method in the controller and it call the "create" method then it does not work. It's the proper way to contract a hash manually and sending it to "create" that I seem to not understand.

Comment: I just found that there is something wrong in the way you call that method from your view. Now you have defined method as "computenew" but really it should be :post (for example), try that
call it like this: 

{ controller: "slot", action: "computenew", method: :post }

Comment: @hmartinezd Tried that but now that gives me routing issue (admittedly I am not an expert in routes). I got:

No route matches {:action=>"computenew", :controller=>"slot", :method=>:post}

Tried to add a route:

resources :slots do
   post  :computenew
end

Got the same error. Made sure that my controller method was available by declaring it in the controller as

"helper_method :computenew"

Comment: really you need only to have
resources :slots 
in your routes file, that will include all the routes. Try doing 
rake routes 
in the command line, and check if there you find the computernew_slots path. Also restart your server.

Comment: @hmartinezd Yeah, with only the "resources :slots" in the route file the route didn't show up but with it I get "slot_computenew POST   /slots/:slot_id/computenew(.:format) slots#computenew" but still get the same exception. And of course I did restart the server each time. Thanks for trying!

Comment: define the resources as " resources :slots do collection do post :computenew end end " that way will have the route /slots/computenew without :slot_id and then do <%= button_to "Compute slot", slot_computenew, method: :post %>

Comment: correction: <%= button_to "Compute slot" {action: "computenew", controller: "slot", slot: "", method: :post} %>

Comment: Unfortunately still get the route error. "No route matches {:action=>"computenew", :controller=>"slot", :slot=>"", :method=>:post}". The route did change as predicted though "computenew_slots POST   /slots/computenew(.:format)     slots#computenew". At least I am leaning things on routing! ;-)

While this is not elegant, I found a way around to my problem however, I have created another model that access the same table, that way I can have one for forms and one for computed insertions. Not very elegant but until I find the correct way, it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The exception you mentioned, it's about the missing parameter `:slot`.

When you do this:

```
params.require(:slot)
```

You tell the controller to raise that exception if the key `:slot` is missing from the `params` hash.

Then you used `button_to` which I don't believe submits the form, instead it acts like a link and redirects the user to the page. So I guess that's why the `:slot` key is missing from parameters.

More info on: https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters AND http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Comment: Maybe my explanation is not clear. No, I don't pass any parameters from the button, it call the "computenew" method which then try to insert the data by calling "create!". This then raise the exception in that case. And yes, obviously I don't create the hash the way that I should be doing it but none of the documentation that you reference or found does address this.

The point is that the documentation all assume that I am using a form (which I don't). The problem is not to do it without a form (I do that by changing the code in create) it is to do it while also being able to use a form.

Answer (score 0):

While this does not solve the problem in the way that I want to solve it, I have found a way around to achieve my goal.

I have created a another MVC called "autoslot" and I am pointing the model to the same table that way:

```
class Autoslot < ActiveRecord::Base
 self.table_name = 'slots'
end
```

That way, I can keep the the slot design as it was originally with manual forms and insertions and I can use the "autoslot" for computed insertions (based on some user settings).

So basically, the goal is achieve even though the way to do it is far from elegant in my opinion.

I am sure there is a better and simpler to do it in Rails (that makes little sense that there is not)... so hopefully, someone will find a better solution!